# VBA JSON parser or DLL

Tags: json, vba

I've tried vba-json but it doesn't handle complex (some nested) JSON strings. Are there any other products out there I could integrate with Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VB6, but likely will work fine under VBA.  I've not used it myself though.
http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html

Tim