# VBA retrieve values from dictionary (JSON Result)

Tags: json, excel, dictionary, vba

I'm writing some VBA code that retrieves results from a web service. Here is the result:

```
Response.Content : "{
    "CancelTaxResult": {
        "DocId": "74856298",
        "TransactionId": 1017269429,
        "ResultCode": "Success"
    }
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the values of DocId, TransactionId, or ResultCode

I see the attached in Watches

[image]

Can someone point me in right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354718/vba-json-parser-or-dll/5355201?s=1|2.3641#5355201 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073370/vba-creating-substrings-out-of-json-and-reformatting-into-columns/15075670?s=3|1.7347#15075670

Comment: Thanks looked at those and still no luck. I'm not looking for a JSON parser. Everything else I have is working,. Just can;t figure this last bit out

Comment: Might help to explain what is we're looking at in that watch window and how you got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

Response.Data("CancelTaxResult")("DocId")